# Dataframe printed to terminal without print() command

Tags: python, pandas, windows, yfinance

I have written some code to download stockprices using Python.

All Tickers (140+, e.g. BMW.DE) have no problems.

I'm having issues with 'CON.DE'. It won't save to a .csv file and more peculiar it prints the dataframe to the terminal without there being a print() command.

I'm running it using the following versions:

- yfinance 0.1.77
- pandas 1.5.0
- python 3.10.8

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import os

curdir = os.getcwd()


def getPrice(ticker):
    df = yf.Ticker(ticker).history(period ='1mo')[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']] #Download pricing
    outputFile = os.path.join(curdir, 'Output', ticker +'.csv') #define path for output file
    df.to_csv(outputFile) #export as .csv

getPrice('CON.DE') #Doesn't save df to .csv and prints df in terminal
getPrice('BMW.DE') #Saves df to .csv without issue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually running into an odd issue with Window's special `CON`(note it's case insensitive) filename which basically is redirecting to the console. This same code works fine in the WSL(linux) or non-windows.

The issue is in the filename. `df.to_csv("con")` produces this behavior so as you start stripping away portions of your `outputFile` when ticket == "CON.DE", you'll notice that breaking up the `CON` part "fixes" this wonky behavior you're seeing.

So this should fix your issue:

```py
outputFile = os.path.join(curdir, 'Output', ticker.replace(".", "") +'.csv') #define path for output file
```

^ the above will strip out the `.` so that the filename here would be "conde.csv" which works fine. You could experiment with some other filenames that fit you better like `ticker.replace(".", "-")` -> "CON-DE.csv" would work fine as well since Windows interpets `.` in a filename a little different than most other characters

Some links that may be more helpful to explain `CON`:

- https://superuser.com/questions/86999/why-cant-i-name-a-folder-or-file-con-in-windows
- [https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/file-name-as-con-cannot-be-created-on-desktop-can/c41e136a-56ac-4385-b119-3773cdee7a9c#:~:text=CON%20is%20a%20reserved%20name,are%20still%20reserved%20in%20Windows](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/file-name-as-con-cannot-be-created-on-desktop-can/c41e136a-56ac-4385-b119-3773cdee7a9c#:%7E:text=CON%20is%20a%20reserved%20name,are%20still%20reserved%20in%20Windows).

Comment: Thank you very much! That fixed it. Serves me right for adding a " ."  to a filename.